# I want to know the difference between can I and could i

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am learning grammar and I feel some confusion between the usage of *can I* and *could I*. Is there some rule I should use?

Comment: The words are used in several contexts.  Perhaps if you posted sentences with the two words.

Comment: Sorry, no hard and fast rule.  The good news is that this is an area where you probably won't get in any hot water for using the "wrong" one!

Answer (score 1):

"**Can I**" is directly asking if (whatever), where as "**Could I**" is more of a hypothetical situation.

Comment: *Can I have some water?* vs *May I have some water?* vs. *Could I have a glass of water?* and  *Can I park here?* vs *Could I park here?* What about: *Can you swim?* vs *Could you swim?* Is just hypothetical? And: *Can I fly tomorrow?* vs. *Could I fly tomorrow?* If you're going to answer a question like this, you're going to have to go into more detail. This "answer" is fine as a comment, nothing else.